# Null Object Reference on PushManager class from AWS Mobile Hub Sample Project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have downloaded a sample project from AWS Mobile Hub with SNS push services integrated with it.

In my existing app, I copied the `com.amazonaws.mobile` package into my application `java` directory. In addition, I've added the AWS gradle libraries into my gradle file of the module, and added the `meta-data` and `receiver` attributes into my manifest file.

In my `MainActivity.java` I have this code:

```
import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager;

private PushManager pushManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    pushManager = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getPushManager();
    toggleNotification(true);
}
```

The `toggleNotification` method is taken from the demo app. The problematic part is the line where I initialize `pushManager` (`pushManager = AWSMobileClient...`). Here is the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.intap.snspushtest, PID: 25796
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intap.snspushtest/com.intap.snspushtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient.getPushManager()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient.getPushManager()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.intap.snspushtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It says that `getPushManager()` is a null object reference, which is weird, since in the sample application it works great, and I didn't change anything on the copied files...

Could you please help me with that? I'm still trying to figure out why is it null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient.getPushManager()' on a null object reference

This indicates that AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient() returned null and therefore getPushManager() could not be invoked. AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(context) must be called first to initialize the mobile client before calling AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().  The initialization is usually performed in the Application class as shown below:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient;

/**
 * Application class responsible for initializing singletons and other common components.
 */
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Initializing application...");
        super.onCreate();
        initializeApplication();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Application initialized OK");
    }

    private void initializeApplication() {

        // Initialize the AWS Mobile Client
        AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(getApplicationContext());

        // ... Put any application-specific initialization logic here ...
    }
}
```